# Second Chern class classifies rank $r$ vector bundle over $S^4$?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, mathematical-physics

On page 16 of Atiyah's Geometry of Yang-Mills Fields (http://plouffe.fr/simon/math/Atiyah%20M.%20Geometry%20of%20Yang-Mills%20Fields%20(Pisa,%201979)(100s).pdf) it stated that

"...the topological theory of fiber bundles over spaces like $S^4$ which are not contractible tells us that in this case they are precisely classified by the [same] integer $k$ (= second Chern class)".

So I'm just wondering if this is saying that a $SU(r)$-bundles $E \rightarrow S^4$ are classified by $c_2(E)$? In particular, if $E,E'$ are two $SU(r)$-bundles over $S^4$ and $c_2(E) = c_2(E')$ then $E\cong E'$ (isomorphic as vector bundle)?

How do I see that this result is true?
What is a generalization of this result? Would it remain true for any simple Lie group $G$ instead of $SU(r)$? In particular, how do I know when do Chern classes classifies vector bundles over a topological space?

Comment: [A similar question on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/195592/21564).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result generalises to principal $G$-bundles over a 4-dimensional complex $X$, where $G$ is any simply connected Lie group.

Recall that any principal $G$-bundle $P\rightarrow X$, over any finite complex $X$, is classified by the homotopy class of map $f:X\rightarrow BG$, into the classifying space of $G$, in that there is a bundle isomorphism $P\cong f^*EG$ over $X$, where $EG\rightarrow BG$ is the universal $G$-bundle with contractible total space.

Now the restrictions on $G$ imply that $\pi_0G=\pi_1G=\pi_2G=0$, and $\pi_3G\cong \mathbb{Z}^r$ for some integer $r$. Since there is a homotopy equivalence $\Omega BG\simeq G$ this implies that $\pi_0BG=\pi_1BG=\pi_2BG=\pi_3BG=0$ and $\pi_4BG\cong\mathbb{Z}^r$.

Now choose a map $c:BG\rightarrow K(\pi_4BG,4)$, which induces an isomorphism on $\pi_4$. This map is 5-connected, so induces an isomorphism $H^4(K(\pi_4BG,4))\cong H^4(BG)=\mathbb{Z}^r$, and, in particular, takes the fundamental classes in $H^4(K(\pi_4BG,4))$ to the 'Chern' classes in $H^4(BG)$.

In case $X$ is a 4-dimensional complex we get an isomorphism $c_*:[X,BG]\xrightarrow{\cong}[X,K(\pi_4BG,4)]\cong H^4(X;\pi_4BG)\cong H^4(X;\mathbb{Z}^r)\cong \oplus^rH^4(X)$, which  takes the class of the map $f$ classifying the bundle $p$ to the value of the degree 4 characteristic class in $BG$.

Since $c_*$ is an isomorphism, this class completely characterises the isomorphism class of the bundle $P\rightarrow X$.

In particular when $G=SU(r)$ and $X$ is a 4-dimensional complex, the bundle $P$ is completely characterised by its second Chern class $c_2(P)\in H^4(X)$. If $G=Sp(r)$ and $X$ is as above, then the bundle is completely characterised by its first symplectic pontrjagin class $q_1(P)\in H^4(X)$. If $G=Spin(r)$ and $X$ is as before, then $P$ is characterised by its first Pontrjagin class  $p_1(P)\in H^4(X)$. The construction I outline above holds when $G$ is any product of such simple, simply connected Lie groups (which covers all such compact, simply connected lie groups).

Observe also that when $X$ is 4-dimensional then obstruction theory gives shows that any $SU(r)$-bundle has a reduction of structure to an $SU(2)$-bundle. Similarly $Sp(r)$-bundles over $X$ always reduce to $Sp(1)$-bundles, and $Spin(r)$-bundles always reduce to $Spin(4)$-bundles. Since $SU(2)\cong Spin(3)\cong Sp(1)\cong S^3$, and $Spin(4)\cong Spin(3)\times Spin(3)$ the characteristic classes in degree 4 are all essentially the same.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you expand a bit more how the map $c$ is defined and why do we have $c_*([f]) = c_2(f^*EG)$? (That is what you are saying when you talked about the isomorphism $[X, BG]\cong \oplus^rH^4(X)$, right?)

Comment: Recall that for any space $Y$, any abelian group $A$ and any $n\geq 0$ we have an isomorphism $\theta:[Y,K(A,n)]\cong H^n(Y;A)$, $f\mapsto f^*\iota$, where $\iota$ is the fundamental class in $H^n(K(A,n),A)$. To get the map $c$, we take $Y=BG$, $A=\mathbb{Z}$ and $n=4$, choose suitable generators $\underline c$ of $H^4(BG;\mathbb{Z})$ (which will be our 'Chern' classes), and let $c$ be the preimage of these generators under the isomorphism $\theta$. That is, $\underline c=c^*\iota$. Hence $c$ is tautologically defined to correspond to the degree 4 characteristic classes.

Comment: Given $f:X\rightarrow BG$ we have $c_*f=c\circ f=f^*c\in [X,K(\mathbb{Z},4)]$. Thus $\theta(c_*f)=(c\circ f)^*\iota=f^*c^*\iota=f^*\underline c$, so $f$ indeed pulls back the universal characteristic classes.

Comment: I think you should bear in mind that the *Chern classes* are even degree characteristic classes for principal $U(n)$-bundles, or, equivalently, complex vector bundles. Unless there is a canonically defined representation of $G$ in $U(n)$ (say for the case $SU(n)$, or for the low-dimensional accidental isomorphisms I discuss above) it doesn't really make sense to ask for *Chern classes* of a $G$-bundle. I've discussed above why there are also degree 4 characteristic classes for $G$ simply connected compact Lie, but these should not be confused with Chern classes.

Comment: So basically, for $G = SU(n)$ we have $\pi_4 BG = \mathbb{Z}$ so $r = 1$ and $H^4(BG)$ is generated by $c_2(EG)$. So we define $c:BG\rightarrow K(\pi_4BG,4) \cong BG$ such that $c_2(EG) = c^*(i)$. Then $c_*$ is an isomorphism. Given a complex vector bundle $E\rightarrow X$, we find $f:X\rightarrow BG$ such that $E = f^*EG$, then $c_*f = f^*c_2(EG) = c_2(f^*EG) = c_2(E)$. Therefore we conclude that $E = E'$ iff $c_2(E) = c_2(E')$ because $c_*$ is an isomorphism. Is basically correct?

Comment: I still got a few more questions, I hope you don't mind. The cohomology class that classifies bundle, in general, will be the generator of $H^4(BG)$? The reason why we have to pick generators $\underline{c}$ is that the map $c$ wouldn't be homotopy equivalent otherwise (hence $c_*$ won't be an isomorphism)? If $r\neq 1$ or $H^4(BG)$ has more than one generator, then would that mean the bundle $E$ is determined by $r$ characteristic classes and we are allowed to pick any one of the generators?

Comment: We know that there is an bijection $Prin_G(X)\cong[X,BG]$ between principal $G$-bundles over $X$ and homotopy classes of maps $X\rightarrow BG$, given by taking a bundle $E$ to the unique homotopy class $[f]$ belonging to some map $f$ satisfying $E\cong f^*EG$. This is the content of the classifying space construction, see Husemoller's book, "Fibre Bundles", for example.

Comment: When $X$ is 4-dimensional and $G$ is simply connected compact Lie then $c_*:[X,BG]\rightarrow [X,K(\pi_4BG,4)]$ is an isomorphism. The latter homotopy set is isomorphic to $H^4(X;\pi_4BG)$. Hence $Prin_G(X)\cong[X,BG]\stackrel{c_*}{\cong}[X,K(\pi_4BG)]\cong H^4(X;\pi_4(BG))$. In particular this holds for $G=SU(n)$, which has $\pi_4BSU(n)\cong\pi_3SU(n)\cong\mathbb{Z}$. The map $c=c_2$ is induced by the second Chern class in this case, so we conclude that $E\cong E'$ (note isomorphism, not equality) if and only if $c_2(E)=c_2(E')$.

Comment: Observe that the map $c$ is not a *homotopy equivalence* it is a 5-equivalence, or 5-connected map. This means that it induces isomorphisms on $\pi_i$ for $i=0,\dots,4$, and an epimorphism on $\pi_5$. This gives a bijection $c_*[X,BG]\xrightarrow{\cong}[X,K(\pi_4BG,4))]$ because we have assumed that $X$ is a 4-dimensional complex. This can be shown, for instance, by obstruction theory. See Arkowtiz, "Introduction to Homotopy Theory".

Comment: The reason we pick generators $\underline c$ is so that the induced map $H^4(K(\pi_4BG,4))\rightarrow H^4(BG)$ is an isomorphism. In this case this then tells us that $\pi_4BG\rightarrow \pi_4K(\pi_4BG,4)$ is an isomorphism, which is what tells us that $c$ is 5-connected. In fact $\underline c$ needs to contain generators for each summand appearing in $\pi_4BG$, and no less. For instance if $G=SU(n)\times SU(m)$, then $\pi_4BG=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$, and we need to pick generators corresponding to each of the summands, so the map $c$ will contain the information of a pair of Chern classes

Comment: Umm... That's the part I'm not sure. If $G = SU(n)\times SU(m)$ then $\pi_4BG = \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}$ then does it mean that we pick $\underline{c} \in H^4(BG, \pi_4BG) = H^4(BG, \mathbb{Z})\oplus H^4(BG, \mathbb{Z}) = (\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z})\oplus (\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z})$ to be $\underline{c} = ((1,0),(0,1))$? ($H^4(BG) = Hom(H_4(BG), \mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}$ because $H_3(BG) = 0$ and $H_4(BG) = \pi_4(BG)$ by Hurewicz theorem, am i right?)

Comment: The 5-equivalence $c:BG\rightarrow K(\pi_4BG,4)$ should be chosen to induce an isomorphism on $\pi_4$. Your choice of $\underline c=((1,0),(0,1))$ is the correct one, since it corresponds to the identity $\mathbb{Z}^2\xrightarrow{=}\mathbb{Z}^2$ in the group $Hom(\mathbb{Z}^2,\mathbb{Z}^2)$, which is going to factor into our calculations through the universal coefficient theorem. The choice $((1,1),(1,1))$, is *incorrect*, since it would correspond to two copies of the fold map $\mathbb{Z}^2\xrightarrow{+}\mathbb{Z}$, and not produce an isomorphism in homotopy.

Comment: I see, I should think of $\underline{c} = ((1,0),(0,1))$ as $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ shouldn't I? In general, if $\pi_4BG = \mathbb{Z}^r$ and $\pi_{<4}BG = 0$ then $\underline{c} \in H^4(BG, \pi_4BG) = Hom(H_4(BG),\pi_4BG) = Hom(\mathbb{Z}^r, \mathbb{Z}^r)$ can be any invertible integer $r\times r$-matrix, is that right?

Comment: Yes. And the choice of such a matrix would correspond to a collection of degree 4 characteristic classes whose aggregate would give a classification scheme for $G$-bundles over 4-complxes. Choosing a different matrix would simply give a different, but equivalent, classification.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much for your help.